# Google Apps Script - Copy a range of cells, depending on the value of one cell

Tags: google-apps-script

I think I have a basic problem. I just started using Google Apps a few days ago:

I have a table in a sheet with some information about a week of the year (some tasks I have to do). Then on next Monday I want to click a button and create a new table below the existing table with the same data but for the next week (I always have to copy the latest table that cointains the latests tasks, that's why I put the backwards the ´for´).

I have tried the following but random ranges are copied except for the one of the table I need.

Thank you!

```
***function NewWeek() 
{
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Lydia");
  var range = sheet.getDataRange();
  var last = range.getLastRow();

//------------------------------------------------------------------

for(initial = last ; initial >= 6; initial--) // row 6 is the start of the initial table header.
{
  Logger.log(initial);
// if going backwards the cell value is equal initial date it copies the range of the latest table.
  if(sheet.getRange(initial,2).getValue == "Initial Date");
  {
  sheet.getRange(initial,2,last,19).copyTo(sheet.getRange(last + 4, 2), 
  SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_NORMAL,false);
  }
}
}***
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function NewWeek() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet12");
  var last = sheet.getLastRow();

  //------------------------------------------------------------------

  for (initial = last; initial >= 6; initial--) // row 6 is the start of the initial table header.
  {
    Logger.log(initial);
    // if going backwards the cell value is equal initial date it copies the range of the latest table.
    if (sheet.getRange(initial, 2).getValue == "Initial Date");
    {
      sheet.getRange(initial, 2, last - initial + 1, 19).copyTo(sheet.getRange(last + 4, 2),
        SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_NORMAL, false);
    }
  }
}
```

I recreated this in my sheet. The following code works. There are two changes.

1. access last row of sheet rather than range.
2. the copy number of rows to copy is given by `last-initial+1`

Comment: Hey Hemanta thanks for your reply. This works now and copies the exact range of the table. However, the 'for' goes until 6, and after you create the second table, then it copies both tables (the last and first, assuming you ran it once), not only the last that is the most updated one. Is there any way to make it stop, when it finds the name of the first column ("Initial Date") of the last table?

Comment: Please identify the number of rows of last updated table. Let it be x
Then, use `for (initial = last; initial >= last-x+1; initial--)`

Comment: Sorry Hemant I get your point, but these tables vary in the amount of rows. I am trying to figure out how to count the number of rows for the last table, to replace "x". Could you please illustrate here? That's what is missing. Because I have "last" that return the last row, now I need something that counts from bottom-up, to know the number of rows of the last table. I supposed is a missing variable here..

Comment: Assuming that you have blank rows between the tables and there are multiple weeks table already. 
`var last = sheet.getLastRow();
  var range = sheet.getRange("B" + last);
  if (range.getValue() == "") {
   x=last;
  } else {
    x=range.getNextDataCell(SpreadsheetApp.Direction.UP).getRow();
  } `